# missing zlib when configuring dropbear

Tags: software-installation

when I ran `./configure` in dropbear, it says missing zlib;
however, I've already added the prefix, i.e., `--prefix`, to point to the correct directory for zlib, but the problem still persists.

I'm trying to build the files in dropbear by running

```
#!/bin/bash
./configure --prefix=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/dropbear \
            --with-zlib=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib/include \
            --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-gcc
```

but it seems that it's unable to local the path to zlib.

Comment: What do you mean by _...the correct directory for zlib..._? Moreover, `--prefix` indicates where you want to install software, not where `configure` is supposed to find it.

Comment: my apologies, what I meant was when I try to build the files in dropbear by running `#!/bin/bash

./configure --prefix=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/dropbear --with-zlib=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib/include --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-gcc` but it seems that it's unable to local the path to zlib

Answer (score 0):

The configure option `--prefix` is used to tell the configure script (and the resulting makefiles) where to **put** the programs which will be installed.  It does not tell where to **get** header-files and libraries.

To tell the configure script where to get files, you may have to adjust these variables:

- CPPFLAGS (for directories containing header-files)
- LDFLAGS (for directories containing libraries)
- LIBS (for the actual library names)

You can pass those values on the command-line to configure, e.g.,

```
myheader=$HOME/junk/include
mylibs=$HOME/junk/lib
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I$myheader" LDFLAGS="-L$mylibs"
```

Following up on the clarification (which should have been incorporated into the question)

> when I try to build the files in dropbear by running
>
> `#!/bin/bash
>   ./configure --prefix=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/dropbear --with-zlib=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib/include --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-gcc`
>
> but it seems that it's unable to local the path to zlib

You can see the problem by looking at the source for the [configure script](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/master/configure.ac#L99):

```
# Check if zlib is needed
AC_ARG_WITH(zlib,
    [  --with-zlib=PATH        Use zlib in PATH],
    [
        # option is given
        if test -d "$withval/lib"; then
            LDFLAGS="-L${withval}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
        else
            LDFLAGS="-L${withval} ${LDFLAGS}"
        fi
        if test -d "$withval/include"; then
            CPPFLAGS="-I${withval}/include ${CPPFLAGS}"
        else
            CPPFLAGS="-I${withval} ${CPPFLAGS}"
        fi
    ]
)
```

That is, it expects the option value to be the pathname of a directory which contains both the `include` and `lib` subdirectories (or a directory containing the files expected to be in those subdirectories).  The comment shows that the given value was the pathname of the `include` (sub)directory.  The following [compile/link check](https://github.com/mkj/dropbear/blob/master/configure.ac#L130) will fail:

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(z, deflate, , AC_MSG_ERROR([*** zlib missing - install first or check config.log ***]))
```

The likely fix: change that option to

```
--with-zlib=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib
```

Comment: hi Thomas, it's weird, when I removed CC path away I was able to compile but it's for x86-64 intel platform. I need to compile for ARM embedded, so is there anything wrong with the CC path itself?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

myheader=$HOME/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib/include
mylibs=$HOME/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib/lib

./configure --prefix=/home/aa/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/dropbear-arm -v CPPFLAGS="-I$myheader" LDFLAGS="-I$mylibs" --with-zlib=$HOME/Hi3536_SDK_V2.0.4.0/zlib --host=arm CC=arm-hisiv400-linux-gcc`

Comment: perhaps - but if you read `config.log`, you can see what was tried, and what failed.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `config.log` file.  Odds are, you'll find repeated error messages about `-Wno-pointer-sign`.

What's happening isn't that `configure` is failing to find zlib, it's that `configure` is expecting a newer version of GCC than you're using, and GCC is erroring out on the unrecognized command-line option.  *All* the tests are failing, it's just that the test for zlib is the first one where failure is fatal.

To fix this, edit the `configure` script to remove `-Wno-pointer-sign` from the CFLAGS parameters (for me, it was on line 3135).